# Alternative to "Echo" to output intermediate steps

Tags: printing

I want to see the intermediate steps of my Program.I have placed Echo in places where it matters such as before plugging in a relation and before simplifying the expression,so that i can see all the steps in detail.However i want it as a standard output.Print command does not do the job.Is there some solution?My Program does use a package called feyncal

```
DeclareNonCommutative[SuperMinus[\[Phi]]]
DeclareNonCommutative[SuperPlus[\[Phi]]]
(Column[#1, Center] & )[NestWhileList[
     Echo[Expand[DotSimplify[Echo[#1 /. SuperPlus[\[Phi]] . SuperMinus[\[Phi]] -> D + 
      SuperMinus[\[Phi]] . SuperPlus[\[Phi]]]]]] & , 
        Echo[Total[Apply[Dot, Permutations[{SuperPlus[\[Phi]], SuperMinus[\[Phi]], 
         SuperPlus[\[Phi]], SuperMinus[\[Phi]]}], {1}]]], 
          !FreeQ[#1, SuperPlus[\[Phi]] . SuperMinus[\[Phi]]] & ]]
```

[image]

Comment: [Sow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [Reap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)?

Comment: I am going to try them.Unfortunately i have not yet learned these mysterious functions.

Comment: @Alan Thankyou so much!I was able to do what i wanted.Please can you put your suggestion in answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace each instance of `Echo` with [Sow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and wrap the entire resulting expression in a [Reap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).